# Date range array excluding the Sunday & the holiday in PHP

Tags: php, date, date-range

I have a function which returns all the dates between two dates in an array, But I need to exclude Sundays in that array.

```
public function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) { 
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);
    while( $current <= $last ) { 
        $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

After excluding the Sundays, I have a table where I will be storing some dates, I need to exclude those dates from the array too.

like, If I enter the date range as 01-05-2012(DD-MM-YYYY) to 10-05-2012,
The 06-05-2012 will be Sunday & the date 01-05-2012 & 08-05-2012 will be in the table which I mentioned above,
The final out put should be like,

```
02-05-2012
03-05-2012
04-05-2012
05-05-2012
07-05-2012
09-05-2012
10-05-2012
```

How to do this in PHP ?
I tried some but couldn't find the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Sundays part:

```
public function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) { 
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);
    while( $current <= $last ) { 
        if (date("D", $current) != "Sun")
            $dates[] = date($format, $current);
        $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

For the holidays part:

First you need to load the dates into some kind of array and then loop through the array for each of your dates and check if they match.

Comment: I'd use
    date('w', $current) != 0

Comment: I got the @jimpic 's solution after posting the question here, But I think solution is pretty better, anyways thanks for you both, But I'm pretty confused with the holidays part.

Comment: I fixed that holidays part too :)

Comment: you could post your solution in case anyone else has the same problem, otherwise they will only see the question here :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question, Thanks for the people who helped me.

```
public function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'd/m/Y' ) { 
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last = strtotime($last);
    while( $current <= $last ) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ost_holidays where holiday_date='".date('Y-m-d', $current)."' LIMIT 1";
        $sql = db_query($sql);
        $sql = db_fetch_array($sql);
        if($sql['holiday_date'] != date('Y-m-d',$current))
            if (date('w', $current) != 0)
            $dates[] = date($format, $current);
            $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
}
```

The above code is for removing the holidays & the Sundays in the given range.

Comment: Making iterated trips to the db doesn't seem advisable to me.

Answer (score -1):

I did this same above method in Jquery

```
//Convert dates into desired formatt
 function convertDates(str) {
     var date = new Date(str),
         mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
         day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
     return [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
 }

 // Returns an array of dates between the two dates
 var getDates = function(startDate, endDate, holidays) {
     var dates = [],
         currentDate = startDate,
         addDays = function(days) {
             var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
             date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
             return date;
         };
     while (currentDate <= endDate) {
         dates.push(currentDate);
         currentDate = addDays.call(currentDate, 1);
     }
     return dates;
 };
 //Indise Some Function
 var datesTemp = [];
 var dates = getDates(new Date(prodDet.details.date1), new Date(prodDet.details.date2));
 dates.forEach(function(date) {
     if (date.getDay() != 0) {
         datesTemp.push(convertDates(date));
     }
 });
 datesTemp.forEach(function(date) {
     for (var j = 0; j < prodDet.holidays.length; j++) {
         if ((prodDet.holidays[j] != date)) {
             ideal.idates.push(date);
         }
     }
 });
 console.log(ideal.idates);
 //Function Ends Here
```