# How To Remove Duplicate Elements from array after merging with another array in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to Write Program for Calculating Next 20 dates After Specifying Start date, then from 20 dates i have Exclude Weekends & `Holidays(Array holidays('2016-12-13',2016-12-24))` And Result Array which includes only Working Days Excluding Saturday & Sunday, from this Result Array after Passing Holiday `array(Eg:- holidays('2016-12-13',2016-12-24)))`, it must be Excluded from result array. i:e;

> I want Expected Output Below mentioned

.

```
    <?php 
$Date=array('2016-12-01');
echo "\n <br />Start Date:-" . $Date[0] . ""; 

                            /*Code For Generating Next 20 Dates Starts*/
//$start = strtotime($s_row['schedule_start_date']);

$start = strtotime('2016-12-01');
$dates=array();
for($i = 0; $i<20; $i++)
{
    array_push($dates,date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i day", $start)));
}
echo "\n <br /> Array Of next 20 Days/dates of Given:-";
print_r($dates);

$start=array();
$start=$dates;                            /*Code For Generating Next 20 Dates Ends*/
$result=array();

$start = strtotime(array_values($Date)[0]);
//$end = strtotime(array_values($Date)[30]);
$result = array();
$begin = new DateTime( '2016-12-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '' );
//$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date)
{
   //echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
   if (date('N', $start) <= 5)     /* 'N' number days 1 (mon) to 7 (sun) */
                                    /*5 weekday */   
   {
        $current = date('Y-m-d', $start);     //m/d/Y
        $result[$current] = '';

    }
    $start += 86400;
    //echo "Days Without Sat Sun".$result[date($date->format("Y-m-d"))];
      //echo "Days Without Sat Sun".$result2[date($current->format("Y-m-d"))];  

} 
echo " \n <br /> Dates Without Weekends LIKE (Excluding Saturday & Sunday):-";
print_r($result);



        /*For Holiday*/
$FinalArray = array();        
$holidays = array(
  '2016-12-13',
  '2016-12-24',
);
echo " \n <br /> Given Holiday Dates Are:-";
print_r($holidays);



$a1 = $result;
 $a2 = $holidays;
 $array =  array_diff(array_merge($a1,$a2),array_intersect($a1,$a2));

echo "\n <br /> Output:-";
 print_r($array);

?>
```

**it Gives Output as :-** `Array ( [2016-12-01] => [2016-12-02] => [2016-12-05] => [2016-12-06] => [2016-12-07] => [2016-12-08] => [2016-12-09] => [2016-12-12] => [2016-12-13] => [2016-12-14] => [2016-12-15] => [2016-12-16] => [2016-12-19] => [2016-12-20] => [2016-12-21] => [2016-12-22] => [2016-12-23] => [0] => 2016-12-13 [1] => 2016-12-24 )`

**> But I Want Expected Output:-**

```
 Array ( [2016-12-01] => [2016-12-02] => [2016-12-05] => [2016-12-06] => [2016-12-07] => [2016-12-08] => [2016-12-09] => [2016-12-12] => [2016-12-14] => [2016-12-15] => [2016-12-16] => [2016-12-19] => [2016-12-20] => [2016-12-21] => [2016-12-22] => [2016-12-23]
```

You Can Notice That `2016-12-13` is Not There in Above Expected Output as in '2016-12-13', 2016-12-24 is passed as Holiday via holiday array `($holidays = array( '2016-12-13', '2016-12-24', );)` i:e; if i pass any date through holidays array it should not be included in result `Array(). i:e 2016-12-13` is Available in Result array as well as holiday array So While while printing Final **OUTPUT:-** `13th date(2016-12-13)` Should not be Included in final Output. Anybody Solve this will be Appreciated Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in-spite of using built-in php array functions, Solution in any other way using foreach loop or any function will appreciated

Comment: array_unique() function may help you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10595524/2943403

Answer (score 1):

When I have to remove duplicates from a array the function that I keep going back to is

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

you can find the documentation [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
  $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
  $result = array_unique($input);
  print_r($result);
?>
```

the output

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

I hope that this was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to calculate all dates just in one pass. (You may skip filling `$dates` and `$dates_mon_fri` arrays if they doesn't used in output also.) There is yet another approach to avoid `array_diff()` and `array_unique()` functions. I've used an `array_flip()` to exchange keys with values in `$holdidays` array to use fast `array_key_exists()` function.

```
<?php

$start = strtotime('2016-12-01');

$holidays = [
  '2016-12-13',
  '2016-12-24',
];

$dates = [];
$dates_mon_fri = [];
$dates_working = [];
$flip_holidays = array_flip($holidays);

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+$i day", $start);
    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);

    $dates[] = $date;

    $mon_fri = false;
    if (date('N', $timestamp) <= 5) {
        $dates_mon_fri[] = $date;
        $mon_fri = true;
    }

    if ($mon_fri && !array_key_exists($date, $flip_holidays)) {
        $dates_working[] = $date;
    }
}

var_dump($dates);
var_dump($dates_mon_fri);
var_dump($dates_working);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using explicit looping:

```
$begin = new DateTimeImmutable('2016-12-01');
$end = $begin->modify('+20 days');

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$allDates = iterator_to_array($daterange);
$datesExcludingWeekends = array_filter($allDates, function ($date) {
     return (int) $date->format("N") < 6;
});
$datesExcludingWeekends = array_map(
    'date_format',
    $datesExcludingWeekends,
    array_fill(1, count($datesExcludingWeekends), 'Y-m-d')
);

$holidays = [
  '2016-12-13',
  '2016-12-24',
];

$datesExcludingWeekendsIncludingHolidays = array_flip(array_merge(
    $datesExcludingWeekends,
    array_diff($holidays, $datesExcludingWeekends)
));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12cb0a48b2aa0c3e92b4a85ed018dec07e87b979).

Also, take a look at the [Carbon library](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/). If you need some exhaustive working with dates this library can really ease your life.